# Transformation of the sentence with reported speech

Tags: tense, exam-questions, reported-speech, transformation

Today I was doing sentence transformation exercises and I found this sentence:

> 1."Yes, I left the door unlocked", said Daisy.
>   2.Daisy ________ the door unlocked. (having)

I had to use from two to five words and I could not change the word in the brackets.

After a bit of research and teacher's advice I filled the second sentence like this:

> 2.Daisy left having the door unlocked. (having)

Is this correct?

I found in the Grammarway 4 (10th edition) that in reported speech Past Simple can be changed to both Past Simple and Past Perfect. After that my teacher told me that it is correct and we change tense to Past Simple when we report something said just a moment ago or when we ridicule someone's behavior.

I would also like to  know if there are any other situations in which we change the tense to Past Simple?

Comment: @user178049 You must use 'having'.

Comment: I think your excersice is wrong. It's impossible to use *present progressive* here. And *left having* does not make sense at all.

Comment: I guess you can't build a grammatically right sentence using those words mentioned, I tried every possible placement but it still doesn't fit.

Comment: "Daisy admitted to having left the door unlocked" is grammatical, but I cannot believe that it's the intended answer.

Comment: Daisy left, having left the door unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is from a exercise where the task is to:

> Complete the second sentence in each section using the given word,
>   so that the meaning of this sentence is as close as possible to the initial sentence. You are not allowed to change the given sentences. Do not change the given word. Use from two to five words.

Here's an example from that exercise:

- You must do exactly what the manager tells you. **(carry)**
- You must ___________________ instructions exactly. **(carry out the manager’s)**

According to this information the solution probably is:

- Daisy admitted (to) having left the door unlocked. *(Passive Voice, Reported Speech)*

This is based on this information [[Affirmation in reported speech]](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8I4pfkA3jCUC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=affirmation%20in%20reported%20speech&source=bl&ots=5roYLJUVpg&sig=_i89agcc8QjItL9zOzbyaU5Xnu8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0gKeiwKHTAhVLKsAKHVtBBzUQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=affirmation%20in%20reported%20speech&f=false) and this [Source](http://www.grammaring.com/reporting-verb-gerund).

So, your teacher is definitely wrong.

According to [grammar rules](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/) when we use reported speech for **Past Simple** we [change the tense](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech) to **Past Perfect**. However, if we want to report a past action in the *Indirect speech* we can use a **Perfect Participle**. Using the Perfect Participle makes it clear that the action took place in the past.

The general way of reporting the phrase *"Yes, I left the door unlocked", said Daisy.* in the Indirect Speech is:

- Daisy said that she had left the door unlocked.

We can leave the Present tense in the reported speech if what is mentioned is still true at the time of speaking or is generally true.

- "People die", John says.
- John says that people die. (True).

Answer (score -2):

> Daisy, having left the door unlocked, only remembered when she was halfway to Tahiti.

This has nothing to do with past simple or perfect or any verb form.  Instead "having left the door unlocked" is a subordinate phrase that modifies "Daisy" and informs the context of the rest of the sentence.  It's about the only way I can think to fit in "having" in 2-5 words, but it only indirectly relates to the first sentence.

As a kind of English puzzle game, it's fine.  As an exercise I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: It's to see whether you can use and understand the verb *admitted*.

Answer (score -2):

> "Yes, I left the door unlocked", said Daisy.

can be changed to the indirect statement

> Daisy affirmed having left the door unlocked.

*Affirmed* is the appropriate verb that includes the sense of *yes*.

Normally one might want to report Daisy's statement as

> Daisy said yes/affirmed she had left the door unlocked.

except you say that you are supposed to use *having* and not *had*.